# Special words for these personality descriptions

Tags: word-request

I want to know if there are special words as synonyms for these definitions; all are about human characters:

1. Someone who gets carried away easily.
2. Someone whose inner side is a thinker and kinda sad, but his outside deliberately looks like an insane guy.
3. Someone who is gay (happy, not homosexual) without any special reason; or naturally tipsy, needless of alcohol or any kind of drugs.

Comment: Are there three of these, or four?

Answer (score -2):

Could be many. Here I write my choices that come first to my mind.

> 1. [Gullible](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gullible?q=gullible) - *too willing to believe or accept what other people tell you and therefore easily tricked*
> 2. [Thinker^](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thinker) - *One who thinks or reasons in a certain way*
> 3. [Joyful](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/joyful?q=joyful) - *very happy* (You may need to add 'always joyful').

---

^Clarification needed for (2) to connect and clarify what you meant by *the inner and outer side*. Also, a word for the combination of thinker, sad, and insane is doubtful to find.